# How to Generate AWS DynamoDB Credential Key with STS API which is Limited to Insert and Update One Key/Row

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sts

Amazons [STS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/UsingSTS/Welcome.html) allows to create credentials for DynamoDB. I do know how to create time limited (15min - 1h) crediential keys.

However I was wondering whether it is possible to generate a DynamoDB key which is allowed/limited to insert and update only one key/row/record?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write a policy to restrict access to specific keys via [fine-grained access control](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/FGAC_DDB.html).